# Why is my code returning a number lower than what it should return?

Tags: c, debugging, casting, math.h

So I am doing an assignment for a programming course and I am having trouble with one line of my code.

the answer should be (if my math is correct) 40 but the program returns 39.

example:
18.33 * 40 *52 = 38126.4

I then use this code

```
double wage = 0;
wage = wage * 40 * 52;
wage = wage - floor(wage);
wage = wage * 100;
printf(" %d cents", (int)wage);
```

But the program returns 39. If I don't change it to int it is 40.0000000

What is happening?

Comment: How did you declare `wage`?

Comment: ...and what's exactly the content of `wage` just before your piece of code ?

Comment: double wage = 0; wage = wage * 40 *52

Comment: Please edit your question... and show a [MCVE].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating point numbers are incapable of representing every real number to infinite precision. And `40.0` is no exception. Instead, if your calculation is done in a correct and numerically stable way, you'll get the closest number a `double` can represent.

Functions like `printf` make the output pretty by considering how close the operand they received is to a given number.

So your result may be `39.99998`, the closest number a `double` can represent to your correct result. And it is shown as `40.0000000`.

However casting to an `int` performs truncation. So it becomes `39`.

For your purposes (you seem to be dealing in money), an approach which will work best is to get rid of floating point numbers completely. You only need two integers. One for cents (which grows only up to 100), and one for dollars<sup>1</sup>.

<sub><sup>1</sup> I assume dollars and cents because of the multiplication by `100` in your code. Naturally it applies for any currency</sub>

Comment: Thanks. I solved my need for autograder by adding 0.01

Comment: But i'll keep your solution in mind also. Thanks again

Comment: @AncientOwl - That's a brittle fix. It may skew *correct* calculations. I assure you some employers will not like paying an extra cent.

Comment: Adding 0.01 sounds more like a kludge than a fix, the solution proposed by @StoryTeller is a much better idea.

Comment: True but for my current needs it works. This is just a introduction class so i'll learn more as I continue

Comment: @AncientOwl-- I imagine that the assignment was to solve a programming problem, not to find a way to trick the autograder.